# Solaris (UNIX) User Command Logging

Tags: unix, logging, solaris

**Background:**
I have been tasked with performing everyday user tasks on the brutal Oracle Solaris 10 platform and record event logs based on my inputed commands. I'm having trouble trying to understand the logging system behind Solaris and I've read just about every documentation I can and I can't find the answers.

**Question:**
Do the /var/log events log commands such as "successfully" deleting a directory, creating a user, adding a user to a group, etc.? If so, does this save the commands used as well? I tried mucking around with the audit_config files and using the built in audit system but I'm not getting exactly what I want. I'm looking for the "unique" logs of each command result.

p.s - Believe me when I say, I've checked everywhere before asking here.

Your guidance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no. No commands get logged by default in Solaris 10. If it is just your own commands that you want logged, then at the start of your sessions type:

> script -a /log_file_name

That will append to the existing log any commands that you run and the resulting output.

Pressing control + D will finish the logging.

If you have sudo installed, then commands using sudo will be logged. In Solaris 10 though, that is just the current working directory and the command that was run.

Solaris 11 which has sudo installed by default is more interesting in that area as you can turn sudoreplay on, which replays a user's sudo session showing what was entered and any output.